# Multiple triggers on table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I use MS SQL Server Management Studio 2017. I have one trigger (`trigg_1`) which inserts in `table_1` column `col_1` (which is FK to table `table_2`) value from another table (`table_2`). `Trigg_1` works when I insert some values, `trigg_1` inserts value in `col_1`. Now, I need another trigger `trigg_2` that won't let me change col_1. If I disable `trigg_1`, `trigg_2` works.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigg_1]
   ON  [dbo].[table_1] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

update table_1
set col_1=(select col_2 from table_2 where table_1.IDc1=table_2.IDc2);

END
```

This works, but when I want in EDIT TOP 200 ROWS to change the value (now is not null, because `trigg_1` inserted value) col_1, I need `trigg_2`.

Comment: The trigger is updating all rows in the table for every insert because you are not joining to the virtual `inserted` table.

Comment: Do you need trigg_2, which will work when you are trying to change some values in table_1.col_1? What about trigger instead of update? Alse you can use AFTER UPDATE trigger and replace new values with old from table `deleted`.

Comment: I think i'll use the last option. I did it in this way, but I might need trigger. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dependencies of the table from where Insert update fire in this then you can use output clause on insert and update and store into temp table and use accordingly.
you can refer this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-update-statements.